# Is the multiplicative (chain) rule for conditional probability valid for infinitely many events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

So for $n$ events $A_{1}, ...,A_{n}$ the chain rule for conditional probability states that

$P(A_{1} \cap....\cap A_{n}) = P(A_{1})\times... \times P(A_{n}|A_{1}\cap....\cap A_{n-1})$

What about infinitely many events?

Comment: I would assume if the limit exists, then certainly. However, there may by some duality here with [Infinite Disjunctions and Conjunctions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123649/infinite-disjunctions-and-conjunctions) which is riddled with nuance.

Comment: Thanks @Graviton

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's no issue. The LHS is a (weakly) *decreasing* sequence of non-negative real numbers so it must have a limit, and same for the RHS, and those limits must agree because they are the same sequence.

Comment: What is the exact sequence you are referring to on the LHS, and why is it decreasing sequence? @Qiaochu Yuan

Comment: @Astral: I mean the sequence of probabilities $p_n = \mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_n)$. You keep taking intersections so $A_1 \cap \dots \cap A_n$ is a decreasing sequence of sets, so the corresponding probabilities are also decreasing.

Comment: Thank you @Qiaochu Yuan